# Unable to resolve module react-number-format

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

New to react native, but I've seen the "unable to resolve module" error a lot.
This time, I got the error with the react-number-format module after I tried to install react-native-imaged-card-view from this link https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-imaged-card-view using npm.

I would like tips on how to troubleshoot this issue and any other unable to resolve issue, because this happens quite frequently.

```
iOS Bundling failed 20323ms
Unable to resolve module react-number-format from /Users/davidooooo/Documents/redoKoho/NewKoho/node_modules/react-native-star-review/lib/src/components/StarReview.js: react-number-format could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../../node_modules
  3 | import styles, { _reviewTextStyle } from "./StarReview.style";
  4 | import { View, Text } from "react-native";
> 5 | import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
    |                           ^
  6 | import Icon from "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons";
  7 |
  8 | const StarReview = props => {
```

Comment: Which version of react-number-format are you using? Please also post your `package.json`.

Comment: I was actually able to get past this by just reinstalling react-number-format. Thanks!